# scala, play, futures: combining results from multiple futures

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, future, playframework-2.1

I am using:

- Scala 2.10
- Play 2.1

Currently, I am using the `Future` class from `scala.concurrent._`, but I'm open to trying another API.

I am having trouble combining the results of multiple futures into a single List[(String, String)].

The following `Controller` method successfully returns the results of a single Future to an HTML template:

```
  def test = Action { implicit request =>
    queryForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => Ok("Error!"),
      query => {
        Async { 
          getSearchResponse(query, 0).map { response =>
            Ok(views.html.form(queryForm,
              getAuthors(response.body, List[(String, String)]())))
          }
        }
      })
  }
```

*The method `getSearchResult(String, Int)` performs a web service API call and returns a Future[play.api.libs.ws.Response].  The method `getAuthors(String, List[(String, String)])` returns a List[(String, String)] to the HTML template.*

Now, I am trying to call `getSearchResult(String, Int)` in a `for` loop to get several Response bodies.  The following should give an idea of what I'm trying to do, but I get a compile-time error:

```
  def test = Action { implicit request =>
    queryForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => Ok("Error!"),
      query => {
        Async {
          val authors = for (i <- 0 to 100; if i % 10 == 0) yield {
            getSearchResponse(query, i)
          }.map { response =>
            getAuthors(response.body, List[(String, String)]())
          }

          Ok(views.html.form(queryForm, authors))
        }
      })
  }
```

*type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.concurrent.Future[List[(String, String)]]] required: List[(String, String)]*

**How can I map the responses of several `Future` objects to a single `Result`?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a Future parametrized by a List or other Collection of the Result type.

From [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/AF_NH2HfHgg):

In Play 1 you can do this:

```
    F.Promise<List<WS.HttpResponse>> promises = F.Promise.waitAll(remoteCall1, remoteCall2, remoteCall3);

    // where remoteCall1..3 are promises

    List<WS.HttpResponse> httpResponses = await(promises); // request gets suspended here
```

In Play 2 less direct:

```
    val httpResponses = for {
  result1 <- remoteCall1
  result2 <-  remoteCall2
} yield List(result1, result2)
```

Comment: Hm, that link helps.  I tried the approach posted by Julian Richard-Foy: `val httpResponses = Promise.sequence(List(remoteCall1, remoteCall2))`.  This has allowed me to get an instance of `Future[IndexedSeq[Response]]`, which is awesome.  However, I'm still trying to map the list of Responses into a single list of [(String, String)].  Right now, it's only mapping the result of the first Future

Comment: @DavidKaczynski In my Java app we wound up writing a small Promise library and created a `Promise.whenAll(Promise...)` method.  So in researching your question I tried Googling for stuff like, "scala play promise from collection," "...from list," etc.  Such a method I would really expect to be very standard.  Also see:  https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/677

Comment: Upon further inspection, the method I described in my first comment worked.  I had another "bug" that was only returning the results from one future.  Once I created a Promise from a sequence of **different** Futures, I was getting all of the responses in a single Future.  Awesome stuff!